# Disable the NavigateUrl property on the HyperLink in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I need disable the **NavigateUrl** property on the **HyperLink** when the value of variable **aut** is less than zero.

I have tried this in code-behind of my .cs page, without success because the **NavigateUrl** property on the **HyperLink** is enabled, although it opens a blank page ( *on window popup* ) in the browser, when click on **ImageUrl**

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

My code below :

**.cs**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {            
        if (aut > 0)
        {
            HyperLink button = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("MMM");
            button.Enabled = true;                
        }
        else
        {
            HyperLink button = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("MMM");
            button.Enabled = false;
            button.NavigateUrl = "";
        }
    }
}
```

**.aspx**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MMM" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="MMM" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("MMM").ToString()) ? String.Format("http://...?sId={0}&s=2", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Base64ForUrlEncode(Eval("id").ToString()))) : "") %>'
            ImageUrl='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("MMM").ToString()) ? "/Images/bullett/redbul.gif" : "/Images/bullett/forestbul.gif")%>'
            ToolTip='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("MMM").ToString()) ? "Not Exists" : "Exists")%>'
            Target="_blank" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Transparent" OnClick="if (!confirm('Confirm ?'))return false;window.open(this.href,'playsample','width=500,height=500,left=100,top=100,scrollbars=yes,dependent=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,status=no,resizable=yes');return false;"
            Enabled='<%#(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("MMM").ToString()) ? false : true)%>'>
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Try replacing your empty string by "#"

Comment: @Aboc: thanks but I don't have changes ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those properties you're setting on your controls in your codebehind are being overwritten by the code within your <% %> tags in your aspx.  For example, whatever you set button.Enabled in your C# code, will be overwritten later on in the page lifecycle by this:

```
Enabled='<%#(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("MMM").ToString()) ? false : true)%>'
```

I'm guessing that all the code like this in your aspx was written by someone else, before you started working on this project?  If so, the easiest solution is probably to remove your GridView1_RowDataBound function, and instead modify the code inside the <% %> tags to change the behavior to what you need.

That being said, I will say that the way you're TRYING to do it is actually more correct.  If you have the luxury of time, and you aren't afraid to refactor that existing code, you could instead move all that logic inside the <% %> tags to your GridView1_RowDataBound function, and remove the <% %> tags from your aspx so that it would just be:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MMM" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="MMM" runat="server">
    </asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Of course, as I said, you would still need to recreate all of that removed logic in your GridView1_RowDataBound function, which I haven't bothered to show here.